# NetSuite Company Information page (Newbie Question)

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Whenever I try to access the Company Information page this error occurs:

"You have entered an invalid form element name. It must be prefixed with "custpage", unique, lowercase, and cannot contain any non-alphanumeric characters (except for the underscore character) in order to be added to the form or sublist."

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a scripting error (I received the same one a few times when I first started with SuiteScript).  But, I've never tried scripting the company info page (I'm assuming you mean the company information about the NS account, and not one of your customers).  Check the scripted records, and see if there is a script on that record (again, I don't believe there is).  Then, contact support, as that sounds like a defect.

If you are talking about a customer record, that just means that there is scripting in play that is trying to create/use custom fields but is not putting "custpage" at the beginning of the field ID.

Comment: I found the script but it was protected by NS and it seems I won't be able to fix this myself. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yep...  I really hate those locked scripts.  They are annoying, to say the least.  And, from a security standpoint, they are completely horrible.